# Windows Indentity Foundation need IIS 7 Windows Authentication

Tags: iis-7, wif

I'm currently trying to do some tutorials on the Windows Identity Foundation, however, I cannot run the sample provided.

It says "Unable to start debugging on the web server, the underlying connection was closed"

I think it is because my machine runs Vista Home Premium, that does not support Windows Authentication for IIS 7.0.

Can someone confirm that this is the cause of being unable to run the WIF sample?

Answer (score 1):

See if this post on social.msdn.microsoft.com fixes the problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/e98aac6a-5edc-4a29-927a-1774d6114404